# Angular Gettext: plural format in .po file

Tags: gettext, po, angular-gettext

Suppose I have this snippet

`<span translate-n="foo" translate-plural="{{ $count }} items" translate>1 item</span>`

What syntax do I have to have in `.po` file to translate it both for singular and plural?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#: .tmp/ui/orders/views/detail.html:1
msgid "{{$count}} ticket selected"
msgid_plural "{{$count}} tickets selected"
msgstr[0] "{{$count}} ticket geselecteerd"
msgstr[1] "{{$count}} tickets geselecteerd"
```

Though I highly recommend using a tool like PoEdit.

See the developer documentation for a full walkthrough: https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/translate/